# keycloak - does keycloak have any endpoint to get list of user paginated

Tags: keycloak

I am trying to get list of user paginated
I tried work with this endpoint

GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users

but the response contain all the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Endpoint **GET** `/admin/realms/{realm}/users` supports pagination *(look at [method source code](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/17d41c472b78b2053165669bc690509bf761e92c/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/services/resources/admin/UsersResource.java#L230))*

Just add query params `first` & `max` to your request. For example: 
`/auth/admin/realms/<your realm>/users?briefRepresentation=true&first=0&max=5`

P.S. Total records count will be returned in response headers

Comment: Is the total records count value still returned? I cannot find it on v20.0.2

Comment: I confirm there is no total count in headers in version 22.0.0

Comment: @shAkur , @TOUDIdel do you use  `briefRepresentation=true` as described? At least it worked on prev. versions. Another way - use **GET** `/{realm}/users/count`

Answer (score 0):

If you desire to know the total pages of the users, you should get the number of records - 1. I saw in the javascript library called keycloak-admin. It is the function count() which I believe returns the total number of pages beginner by 1. If you're using array based pagination, it will work if you count() - 1.